# Remarkable active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, rspec-rails

i'm using  gem Remarkable activerecord for association. i've installed remarkable and remarkable activerecrod  both gem. i've added both gem in my Gemfile. i've added "remarkable_activerecord" as required in spec_helper.rb.

```
               describe Authentication do
                 FactoryGirl.build(:authentication).should belong_to(:user) 
                end
```

i got error: 
**Authentication 
     Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `belong_to' for #**

what should be done now..??  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what `it` refers to by including `subject { something }` right above the test example.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some RSpec syntax. In order to use the "should" assertion, it has to be within an "it" or "specify" block. There are a number of different ways you can do this, but here's one concise way:

```
describe Authentication do
  subject { FactoryGirl.build(:authentication) }
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
end
```

Comment: thanks Beerlington . i've tried it before. it give same result.

Comment: Are you using a gem that includes these helpers such as [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)?